# Problem with iterating a Nd array with reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Alright so I want to print all of the elements in a random N dimensional array via reflection. The solution works great except I have N-1 empty arrays in the end of the `arraysString` string. For example:

```
private int[] arr = {3, 4, 5};
private int[][] arrs = {{3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {3}};
```

Well when I try to serialize the first array, it will print -> [3, 4, 5], but when I print the second one -> [3, 4][3, 4, 5][3][] is printed. I am confused as to why this is happening. Here is my function:

```
private void serializeToArray(Object array, List<String> arraysAsString) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> arrayOutputs = new ArrayList<>();

    int length = Array.getLength(array);
    builder.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Object arrayElement = Array.get(array, i);
        if (isArray(arrayElement)) {
            serializeToArray(arrayElement, arraysAsString);
            continue;
        }
        arrayOutputs.add('"' + arrayElement.toString() + '"');
    }
    builder.append(String.join(",", arrayOutputs));
    builder.append(']');

    arraysAsString.add(builder.toString());
}
```

isArray ->

```
protected boolean isArray(Object obj){
    return obj.getClass().isArray();
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in your code. I suggest using a debugger or adding some println statements to so that you can see what is happening.

Comment: Done @Eran I forgot

Comment: @rghome  Yeah I just needed to think a little more about what happens if an array has only arrays. Then I'll keep entering the loop and since all of the elements will be arrays, I will get out of the loop and still print an empty array

Comment: (1) Is array holding `{1, 2, {"foo"} }` acceptable as input? What should be result for it (what should be expected content of your list of strings)? (2) Why do you actually use list of strings? Wouldn't your code be simpler with single StringBuilder which would also be filled by recursive calls to build single string?

Comment: @Pshemo 1) -> No, 2) Well I use it because I want to serialise the string in JSON. For example [[["3", "4"], ["5", "6"]]] . All of this cannot be done inside the recursion

Comment: i know it looks like reinventing the wheel but it's just a reflection practice

Comment: If that is only for a practice then that is OK. I just hope for real-world application you will use already existing solutions which ware tested by thousands of other programmers :)

Comment: Aside from main question, `if(isArray){codeHandlingArray; continue}codeHandlingNonArray` would be more readable as `if(isArray){codeHandlingArray}else{codeHandlingNonArray}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 2D array input, when the recursive calls return, you add the String `[]` to the output `List`.

To avoid that, change

```
arraysAsString.add(builder.toString());
```

to

```
if (builder.length () > 2 || length == 0) {
    arraysAsString.add(builder.toString());
}
```

This will change the output from

```
[["3","4"], ["3","4","5"], ["3"], []]
```

to

```
[["3","4"], ["3","4","5"], ["3"]]
```

Comment: I considered that solution as well, but if I actually try this with a legit empty array, I want [] to be printed. With this solution, nothing will be printed in this case.

Comment: Alright thanks fixed it by adding a check myself haha

Comment: @ZWar actually, you are right, in order for empty arrays (or sub-arrays) to be printed as [], change the condition to `if (builder.length () > 2 || length == 0)`.

Comment: ^^ the check for the length should happen before we enter the loop. Anyways thanks your answer has helpful

Comment: @ZWar it can work either way (you don't have to test the length before the loop. If the length is 0, the loop will not be executed anyway).